# Seeking clarity the Costmap2D::worldToMapEnforceBounds() function

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [docs](http://docs.ros.org/en/indigo/api/costmap_2d/html/classcostmap__2d_1_1Costmap2D.html#a3ee987fada22fb449072bdd800a18f82) define the `costmap_2d::Costmap2D::worldToMapEnforceBounds(double wx, double wy, int &mx, int &my)` function as follows -

Convert from `world` coordinates to `map` coordinates, constraining results to **legal** bounds.

How does one set the legal bound?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391155/seeking-clarity-the-costmap2d::worldtomapenforcebounds()-function/) by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 310 on 2021-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @skpro19

if you look at the source code of this function it's basically checking the bounds against `origin_x_`, `origin_y` and `resolution_` that are values that are created with an instance of Costmap2D, they also get updated in the event map gets resized. Not a definition of a legal bound, but at least you can see how it's interpreted

```
00228 void Costmap2D::worldToMapEnforceBounds(double wx, double wy, int& mx, int& my) const
00229 {
00230   // Here we avoid doing any math to wx,wy before comparing them to
00231   // the bounds, so their values can go out to the max and min values
00232   // of double floating point.
00233   if (wx < origin_x_)
00234   {
00235     mx = 0;
00236   }
00237   else if (wx >= resolution_ * size_x_ + origin_x_)
00238   {
00239     mx = size_x_ - 1;
00240   }
00241   else
00242   {
00243     mx = (int)((wx - origin_x_) / resolution_);
00244   }
00245 
00246   if (wy < origin_y_)
00247   {
00248     my = 0;
00249   }
00250   else if (wy >= resolution_ * size_y_ + origin_y_)
00251   {
00252     my = size_y_ - 1;
00253   }
00254   else
00255   {
00256     my = (int)((wy - origin_y_) / resolution_);
00257   }
00258 }
```

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1